# Number of sums of factors

Tags: code-golf, math, factoring

Given a positive integer **n > 1** determine how many numbers can be made by adding integers greater than 1 whose product is **n**.  For example if **n = 24** we can express **n** as a product in the following ways

```
24 = 24             -> 24            = 24
24 = 12 * 2         -> 12 + 2        = 14
24 = 6 * 2 * 2      -> 6 + 2 + 2     = 10
24 = 6 * 4          -> 6 + 4         = 10
24 = 3 * 2 * 2 * 2  -> 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 9
24 = 3 * 4 * 2      -> 3 + 4 + 2     = 9
24 = 3 * 8          -> 3 + 8         = 11
```

We can get the following numbers this way:

```
24, 14, 11, 10, 9
```

That is a total of 5 numbers, so our result is 5.

## Task

Write a program or function that takes **n** as input and returns the number of results that can be obtained this way.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with fewer bytes being better.

### OEIS sequence

[OEIS A069016](https://oeis.org/A069016)

Comment: Suggested test case 240

Comment: Since 36 has caused a lot of debate, I suggest it as a test case.

Comment: I don't see how 36 should give 5. I get `[10, 13, 20, 36, 11, 15]` as unique numbers

Comment: @WheatWizard 12 * 3

Comment: I have `2,2,3,3 -> 10`, `2,6,3 -> 11`, `2,2,9 -> 13`, `12,3 -> 15`, `2,18 -> 20`, `36 -> 36`

Comment: `(2*2)+(3)+(3)=10`

Comment: 36 should be 7 because `(2*3)+(2*3)=12` should be in the list too.

Comment: ..and if 36 should output 7 then 240 should output 23.

Comment: Suggested test case: 2310. Should output (I may be wrong) 49.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
{~×≜+}ᶜ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7ru8PRHnXO0ax9um3No5///xmb/owA)

### Explanation

```
{    }ᶜ¹  Count unique results of this predicate:
 ~×       Create list of numbers whose product is the input.
   ≜      Label the list, forcing it to take a concrete value.
    +     Take its sum.
```

I'm not entirely sure why `~×` only produces lists with elements above 1, but it seems to do so, which works great in this challenge.

Comment: It only produces lists with elements above 1 because otherwise there are infinitely many lists, which is often bad in challenges like these.

Answer (score 4):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>9</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Bug fixed at the cost of 5 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan, then 1 byte golfed.

```
ḍfḍ¦e¦Π¦¦Σ¦ul
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@GO3jQgPrQs9dCycwsOLQOSiw8tK835/9/IBAA) or try as a [test suite](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@GO3jQgPrQs9dCycwsOLQOSiw8tK835b2z2aEqrkYmB9qP5K6weNcyxUnjUMFe74FHbxMJH81ceWvYfAA)

#### Explanation

```
ḍ              Prime factors
 f             Permutations
  ḍ¦           Get the partitions of each permutation
    e¦         Dump each list of partitions (1-level flatten the list)
      Π¦¦      Product of each partition
         Σ¦    Sum each group of products
           u   Deduplicate
            l  Length
```

Comment: Can you provide a TIO link containing the corresponding outputs the numbers 1 through 36 inclusive?

Comment: This is exactly like the Jelly answer...

Comment: The OP says the output for 36 should be 5, not 6

Comment: It gives the correct answer for every other number... so I'm not totally sure the 36 -> 5 is right...

Comment: According to OEIS, 36 gives 7 instead of 5, but yours gives 6

Comment: Apparently Gaia leaves out `[6 6]`

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@GO3jQgPrTs3IJDy0Dw3GIQGV@a8/@/sRkA) should work for 14, maybe you can golf it further?

Comment: ... ah you do have a way to flatten by 1 (I had tried to use `Z` for it)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>11 15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

+4 bytes fixing up a bug (maybe a better way?)
-1 byte by abusing symmetry

```
ÆfŒ!ŒṖ€ẎP€S€QL
```

A monadic link taking and returning positive integers

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rRSYpHJz3cOe1R05qHu/oCgFQwEAf6/P//39gAAA)** or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rRSYpHJz3cOe1R05qHu/oCgFQwEAf6/De0DLI2NrM2MjE4uudwO1BMJQtIPGqYo6Brp/CoYW7k//8A)

#### How?

*Updating...*

```
ÆfŒ!ŒṖ€ẎP€S€QL - Link: number, n      e.g. 30
Æf             - prime factors of n        [2,3,5]
  Œ!           - all permutations          [[2,3,5],[2,5,3],[3,2,5],[3,5,2],[5,2,3],[5,3,2]]
    ŒṖ€        - all partitions for €ach   [[[[2],[3],[5]],[[2],[3,5]],[[2,3],[5]],[[2,3,5]]],[[[2],[5],[3]],[[2],[5,3]],[[2,5],[3]],[[2,5,3]]],[[[3],[2],[5]],[[3],[2,5]],[[3,2],[5]],[[3,2,5]]],[[[3],[5],[2]],[[3],[5,2]],[[3,5],[2]],[[3,5,2]]],[[[5],[2],[3]],[[5],[2,3]],[[5,2],[3]],[[5,2,3]]],[[[5],[3],[2]],[[5],[3,2]],[[5,3],[2]],[[5,3,2]]]]
       Ẏ       - tighten                   [[[2],[3],[5]],[[2],[3,5]],[[2,3],[5]],[[2,3,5]],[[2],[5],[3]],[[2],[5,3]],[[2,5],[3]],[[2,5,3]],[[3],[2],[5]],[[3],[2,5]],[[3,2],[5]],[[3,2,5]],[[3],[5],[2]],[[3],[5,2]],[[3,5],[2]],[[3,5,2]],[[5],[2],[3]],[[5],[2,3]],[[5,2],[3]],[[5,2,3]],[[5],[3],[2]],[[5],[3,2]],[[5,3],[2]],[[5,3,2]]]
        P€     - product for €ach          [[30],[6,5],[10,3],[2,3,5],[30],[10,3],[6,5],[2,5,3],[30],[6,5],[15,2],[3,2,5],[30],[15,2],[6,5],[3,5,2],[30],[10,3],[15,2],[5,2,3],[30],[15,2],[10,3],[5,3,2]]
               -   ...this abuses the symmetry saving a byte over P€€
          S€   - sum €ach                  [30,11,13,10,30,13,11,10,30,11,17,10,30,17,11,10,30,13,17,10,30,17,13,10][10,17,11,30,10,17,13,30,10,13,11,30,10,13,17,30,10,11,13,30,10,11,17,30]
            Q  - de-duplicate              [30,11,13,10,17]
             L - length                    5
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html), 206 bytes

```python
k=lambda n,i=2:n/i*[k]and[k(n,i+1),[i]+k(n/i)][n%i<1]
def l(t):
 r=[sum(t)]
 for i,a in enumerate(t):
    for j in range(i+1,len(t)):r+=l(t[:i]+[a*t[j]]+t[i+1:j]+t[j+1:])
 return r
u=lambda n:len(set(l(k(n))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFRS8MwFIWfl18RB0KzVmbTzc1gH2ROEARh@BbyEFmm6bqspOmDv77erKYGSyknJ1/Oze1tvt3X2dC@P5a1PH3sJTaZLikzcz3jRyHNnh8TsNKcZFyLFBZzTQQ31/ohF2ivDrhOHGEI25K33Qm0QPhwtlhnEmuDlelOykqnLtTE71Tet9J8qgRys1oZ2CPMpiVEcQZVuJw5XgmROg4Eq7yoQAgCdZTrLJxH3Xhj5iNa5ZI6gfsReHqr2q52Jc8zPL40fGnQReQMehH8kVlGQBGcgRyjVlHOMmKKgIFeX8QiqrUK/FjrPuQAdhelFZHObyMo3liHrLEY/XeMRp15joZGFqEFzwqE/JSavynRy4yGX0pS6ueoD3hY8@aGiquySxpvTxqrjcPT58eX1@3TFE1U3SqGf93N22633bxP@x8)

### Explanation

```python
    # Finds the prime factors
k=lambda n,i=2:n/i*[k]and[k(n,i+1),[i]+k(n/i)][n%i<1]
    # Function for finding all possible numbers with some repetition
def l(t):
    # Add the current sum
 r=[sum(t)]
    # For each number in the current factors
 for i,a in enumerate(t):
    # For all numbers further back in the current factors, find all possible numbers when we multiply together two of the factors
    for j in range(i+1,len(t)):r+=l(t[:i]+[a*t[j]]+t[i+1:j]+t[j+1:])
 return r
    # Length of set for distinct elements
u=lambda n:len(set(l(k(n))))
```

Comment: [194 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZBRT8MgFIWf11@BS0xgxczSzk1iH8ycyRITk8U35AEzpnSMNS198NdXWKUSm6YcDt89t9z6236dDem78r3X4vSxF8BQLQ1spYUaHqFB7kmOZTjEqiTUzNWMHbkwe@YIrNIMYaZ46jZzhTgz1@oh44kOVZaytjtBi3jqV6ahZdTxTMwsqzhPLXMZtPKicoKjw7kBCgugDJCmO8lGWOnqvV15sxHmU0JXhP3PWoQ4Zhz1jWw7bUuWYTC@JHxJ0HnkDLoI/sgsIiAPzkCOUcsoZxExecCcXl1EEfVaBn7sdR9yHHYXpeWRzm4jKD5YhayxGflXRqKbeY6EixThCp7lSeKnW/9Nl1xmO4wUpQTRZKIOYNiz@obwq7KDtbcndaOMBdPnx@3L5mmaTKRuJQW/7vp1t9us36b9Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 251 bytes

```python
lambda n:1 if n==1else len(set(sum(z)for z in t(f(n))))
f=lambda n:[]if n==1else[[i]+f(n//i)for i in range(2,n+1)if n%i==0][0]
t=lambda l:[l] if len(l)==1else[[l[0]]+r for r in t(l[1:])]+[r[:i]+[l[0]*e]+r[i+1:]for r in t(l[1:])for i,e in enumerate(r)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHdbsIgFMev5SmYyRJomyhtndqFJ2FcdHqqJIiGYrL58h20oWHuaoSQw@F3/ueD27c7X001nPnHoNvL57HFpmFYddhwzkD3gDUY0oMj/f1CHrS7WvzAymBHOmKoX6jjc6SQSaQQSuYeWq3UGKZCmG3NCUhZmJzRwL4qztdSrCVyUUY3QstQQsis6aymPSVzi4OWnUrQgjWSylxY0fhkI5KBh4TK/csfciyjgOACc7@AbR0QS@UAXzc4ODj2XLACp7uMZxntKvFMdh39M7NJgCp6JnKW2iY6m4SpIubt3WjUSa5t5Odc@6jjsbdErUpstk6g9GEXteZk5VNYmXQWuDI2UscWAisRmoaLn6Y7T7ZgtEEL/63wws9EhcviZpVxRBXLdxy5ZuklCuzP9uDurQ73gFOEgNd7pHiZVdkm22aMoV9q/xIbfgA)

The design is basic:

1. factorize n into its prime factors (a prime factor may appear several times : `16 -> [2,2,2,2]`). That's the function `f`.
2. compute the partitions of the list of prime factors, and multiply the factors in each partition. The partitions are found as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30134039, and the products are computed on the fly. That's the function `t`.
3. The final function gets the products of each partition of n and sums them, the get the number of different values.

The result for `2310=2*3*5*7*11` is `49`.

**EDIT** : Maybe needs fix, but I don't have time to look at it now (I'm in a hurry). Hint: is the result correct for `2310=2*3*5*7*11` ? I dont' think so.

**EDIT2** : Huge fix. See above. Previous (buggy) version was:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtBDoIwEEXXcoouZ3QSUOOGpCdBFiW0OAkMpJREvHytZefy/ff@sofXLPc46GcczdT1Rkk9WoHVBli3CZo37fSh0KKbPRjqkEU5kIxpP7DLmNIDDSIWvXU5rL0Nm5cGKhJsLw0wSVny76FYpd4bGSzckmWn@AzZai1t/Euu9KiwLk6LZwkwACPGLw)

`f` computes the factors (, with a `(0, n)` instead of `(1, n)` as first element.

The lambda splits each factor in "sub-factors" and sums the those "sub-factors".

Comment: [-19 bytes.](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoMwEIXhdT1FNoUZDJi2dCPkJNZFQpN0QEeJEfT0aU2hiy4//seb9/Sa@JaDfuTBjPZpBLeDY1hcgmUdYat39FMEIy0SCw98UGyiwBbsXxhErLz@3XSgJGNfd0CSm4bKlo5tNBwcXD@VvOAzaa36/Fcv8q6wrU5zJE4QgBDzGw)

Comment: [-1 byte from @notjagan improvement](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoMwEIXhdT1FNoUZDKgt3YiexLpIaJIO6CgxBXP6tKbQRZcf/@OtMTwXvibX39OkZv1QgtvJMGwmwPaaYS8j2sWDkhqJhQU@KHaRoTPiFwoRC9v/bgaoJeNYDkCSq4rylo6tV@wMXD6VrOAzdc2Y/mIjbzW2xWn1xAEcEGJ6Aw)

Comment: Thanks to @notjagan, but the initial code was so wrong...

Comment: Thanks to @HalvardHummel, but same remark as above.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 110 bytes

```
If[#==1,1,Length@Union[Tr/@Select[Array[f~Tuples~{#}&,Length[f=Rest@Divisors[s=#]]]~Flatten~1,Times@@#==s&]]]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 107 bytes

```
f=(n,o,s=0,i=2,q=n/i)=>(o||(o={},o[n]=t=1),i<n?(q>(q|0)|o[e=s+i+q]||(o[e]=t+=1),f(q,o,s+i),f(n,o,s,i+1)):t)
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
f=(n,                                 //input
   o,                                 //object to hold sums
   s=0,                               //sum accumulator
   i=2,                               //start with 2
   q=n/i                              //quotient
  )=>(
  o||(o={},o[n]=t=1),                 //if first call to function, initialize o[n]
                                      //t holds the number of unique sums
  i<n?(                               //we divide n by all numbers between 2 and n-1
    q>(q|0)|o[e=s+i+q]||(o[e]=t+=1),  //if q is integer and o[s+i+q] is uninitialized,
                                      //... make o[s+i+q] truthy and increment t
    f(q,o,s+i),                       //recurse using q and s+i
    f(n,o,s,i+1)                      //recurse using n with the next i
  ):t                                 //return t
)
```

**Test cases:**

```js
f=(n,o,s=0,i=2,q=n/i)=>(o||(o={},o[n]=t=1),i<n?(q>(q|0)|o[e=s+i+q]||(o[e]=t+=1),f(q,o,s+i),f(n,o,s,i+1)):t)

s= [];

for(i = 1; i <= 103 ; i++) {
  s.push(f(i));
}

console.log(s.join`, `)
```

To verify that the function calculates the correct sums, we can output the keys of the object instead of `t`:

```js
f=(n,o,s=0,i=2,q=n/i)=>(o||(o={},o[n]=t=1),i<n?(q>(q|0)|o[e=s+i+q]||(o[e]=t+=1),f(q,o,s+i),f(n,o,s,i+1)):Object.keys(o))

console.log(f(24));  //9, 10, 11, 14, 24
```